# como cambiar el color de fondo del boton de JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, joptionpane

He intentado con la clase UIManager para cambiar por defecto el color de los botones y nada

```
UIManager UI = new UIManager(); // clase para modificar  JOptionPane
UI.put("OptionPane.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 255, 255));
UI.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 255, 255));
UI.put("Button.background", new ColorUIResource(74, 157, 206));
```

La idea seria cambiar el fondo del color del boton y el color del texto del boton

gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1era Forma**

Reemplaza `new ColorUIResource(74, 157, 206)`con `new java.awt.Color(74, 157, 206)`.

```
UIManager.put("Button.background", new Color(62, 68, 74));
```

Para configurar el color de la fuente

```
UIManager.put("Button.foreground", Color.white);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2da Forma**

Personaliza tu propio botton e insertalo en el cuadro Joption

```
JButton boton = new JButton("Aceptar");
boton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
boton.setForeground(Color.RED);
boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
   }
});
JButton[] botones = { boton };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Mensaje", "Cuadro", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null, botones, botones[0]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias hombre. funciono perfecto!!!